# Hyper-V "Mouse input not captured"

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v

I've installed hyper-v on windows 8, downloaded and added virtual machine from [ms site](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507045111/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575) "Windows 7 IE 8". But I can't use mouse, see message in bottom of window "Mouse input not captured". "Action->Insert Integration Service Setup Disk" and reboot doesn't help, "ctrl+alt+left arrow" doesn't help. What's the problem?
**upd:** I tried this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dau-blog/archive/2012/02/28/mouse-not-captured-in-remote-desktop-session-when-virtual-pc-vhd-file-runs-in-hyper-v.aspx but after 'starting windows' mouse goes away.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Steps to resolve this problem:

1. go to virtual machine
2. go to control panel-> programs and features
3. remove "Virtual PC Integration Components"
4. shut down and turn on virtual machine

You have to do all these steps using keyboard. `Tab` is your best friend here.

Comment: Had same problem with IE8 test VM on Windows 10, and this worked for that too.

Comment: This worked for me using Hyper-V in Windows 10 on a Windows-7 VM.  I had to keyboard drive the Win7 virtual machine to do the uninstall.  After the un-install and a reboot it started working again.  Anyone know why?

Comment: @JohnDyer most likely because the image you are using was made for use with VirtualPC (NOT HyperV). You can download the hyperV images from modern.ie.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this:

On Windows Server 2008 32bit you need to install SP2 for Hyper-V connectivity
(You won't have mouse integration or networking upon base install, and you can't install the Hyper-V integration CD without SP2)
Installing SP2 via mounting a CD ISO is easiest (the ISO is named mu_windows_vista_sp2_x86_x64_ia64_dvd_x15-39754.iso on MSDN)
Note: Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit does not have this problem, but I couldn't find R2 32bit on MSDN.

If you don't have MSDN I imagine you could get an offline install for SP2 and "burn" it to a virtual drive to create an ISO.

PS - It was fun trying to do things in the virtual console without keyboard shortcuts like Alt+Tab

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling "Virtual PC Integration Components" in the virtual machine solved it for me as well.
One addition though: when uninstalling it asked for the installation cd/files.
To tackle this do the following:

-Locate the iso file you originally used to install the integration features;

File name: IntegrationComponents.iso

Probable location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Virtual PC\Integration Components\

-In Hyper-V Manager select the settings for the virtual machine.
Insert IntegrationComponents.iso into the virtual cd/dvd station via Hardware ; IDE controller 1

-(Re)uninstall "Virtual PC Integration Components"